# Breakpoint not firing in Visual Studio 2015 in XAML

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2013

I've a solution with 2 project, one is asp.net web forms project and the second is a silver light application. But when I try to run the web forms application, the break points in it are working. But at the same there is silver light object of the second project is placed on the webform and the silverlight application loads fine, but the breakpoint in that projects XAML file not firing or its not being caught.

Curios to know why the breakpoint in webforms firing and silverlight XAML, the break point 
not firing..

Answer (score 1):

Set Silverlight project as your 'Startup project' and then you should be able to debug code-behind of XAML file.

1.) In **Solution Explorer**, select the desired startup (Silverlight) project within your solution.

2.) On the **Project** menu, choose **Set as StartUp Project**.